# Plus One Button not working in Android

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-plus-one

I need add +1 button to my android app. I try describe my problem:

1. I installed google-play-services through SDK Manager
2. I copied file google-play-services.jar to libs folder which is placed in my project.
3. I don't use Eclipse but I use Android Studio for building of my project, therefore I have to manually write my gradle file to linkig google play services library.
4. I put dependency to my gradle file `compile files('libs/google-play-services.jar')`
5. I used all relevant things for integrate +1 button according those sites:
   https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started
   https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/recommend
6. First problem is Rendering problem and is occured in develope layout of my app. Android Studio writes me in design builder in design mode: "Rendering Problems: following classes could not be instantiated: com.google.android.gms.plus.PlusOneButton ...", but in text mode is no problem.
7. Second problem is when I build my project and run him on my mobile device with Android 2.3.1. Compilation is successful but when it is running on my mobile device applicatin turns off it suddenly.
8. I suspect that all problem is in non correct installation or make dependecy to google play services libs. I don't now how make it correctly.

Comment: Did you add the `/Extras/Google Repository`? also in gradle you can import play services with `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.1.+'` in the dependencies.

Comment: Yes, I installed Google Repository through SDK Manager. I added row compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.1.+' to gradle like you adviced me. Unfortunately, my problem is still remainded.